# PHP - login form. I keep getting "invalid login information"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using phpmyadmin and my database has permission to all privileges. Textfields are named as in the php code, I don't get any errors from dreamweaver. Also when I test this in wamp localhost. I get "invalid login information"... i have created a username and password in my table "users" also added martin as user and 123456 as password... please review my code?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];  //martin
    $password = md5($_POST['password']); //123456
    // connect to server
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if(!$con){
        die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());}
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where usermame = '$username' AND 

    password = '$password'")))
    {//Correct information
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
       die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $expire = time()+60*60*24*30;//1 month
    setcookie("id", $row['id'], $expire);   
    echo "Logged in as <b>".$row['username']."</b>";
    }

    }else{
    //false information
    echo "Invalid login information.";

}

mysql_close($con);
echo $_COOKIE['id'];
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You have a typo in your query: `usermame`.

Comment: Yes I see couple red boxes and says these functions are deprecated no wonder why but yes thanks I will check those articles, thanks again for referring them.

Comment: @MikeW still same results bruh.

Comment: Hey guys, my button looks like this
`<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" />`

Comment: @MartinNewAtCode you have 2 errors 1 is in your query using `usermame` another is that you are converting your password to md5 `md5($_POST['password'])` whereas it looks like your password on the table is plaintext that's why it's not matching. Try removing the md5 on the code or converting your password to md5 on the table.

Comment: @no_juan I love you <33 much love, youre the best!!! WORKED!!!

Comment: Hey guys relax about the typo already fixed that.

Comment: Why not do a select with the supplied username/password and then check number of returned rows instead of the way you currently do it?

Comment: Is your username stored as md5 in db

Comment: @Darren I was taught that way and even my name explains it lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where usermame = '$username' AND 

    password = '$password'")))
```

You are using 'usermame' in place of 'username' in above code.spelling mistake

Comment: I caught that and changed it as @MikeW referred it to me and still same results.

Comment: please check database structure.that you have took 'username' field as 'varchar' and 'password' field as varchar.

Comment: Or one time echo the above query Like this

echo "SELECT * FROM users where usermame = '$username' AND 

    password = '$password'";
and then check it by executing in mysql.